# Samsung Galaxy S II (Android 2.2.3) with MS Exchance Mail Account Zimbra Server

Tags: android, galaxy, zimbra

In my Samsung S2 I have a Microsoft Exchange Mail Account and use a Zimbra Mail Server. 
The standard email app doesn’t render my html mail. I get all the html source code with the mail text. The synchronization with my calendar and mails works perfectly. 
I installed a second mail app called “touchdown” (only 30 day trial) which is able to render the mails correctly. So I guess it’s not the fault of Zimbra.
Does anybody know why I can’t render the mails with the standard mail app? And more important – is there a way or workaround to chance the rendering for html mails?
Help would be much appreciated.

bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that the problem is caused by the new version of Zimbra (7). I have the problem myself, but i just got the phone yesterday and HTML rendering didn't work at all yet. However, a customer of our company told us, that he has the problem only sience Zimbra was updated to the new version.

Edit: As I found out, the problem is on the Samsung Galaxy SII site. However, Zimbra 7.1.3 has kind of a fix for this, it uses the old protocol version for Samsung phones. Update Zimbra, re-create the account on the phone. The Headers wont show anymore. No HTML-Mail though.

Answer (score 1):

Timo's answer is correct.

However if you still have Zimbra6 ther's another problem in the server implementation of ActiveSync protocol.
Zimbra replies to the Android client saying he's AS Protocol version 2.5, so the client won't ask for html emails.
Some other clients, like iPhones, ignores server version and just always ask for html email, regardless of the server.
This behavior was fixed in Zimbra 7:
http://bugzilla.zimbra.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18608